# Split double into two int, one int before decimal point and one after

Tags: c#, double, int, decimal-point

I need to split an double value, into two int value, one before the decimal point and one after. The int after the decimal point should have two digits.

Example:

```
    10.50 = 10 and 50
    10.45 = 10 and 45
    10.5  = 10 and 50
```

Comment: Provided more info, sorry for not being clear.

Comment: Do you actually need it to be in two ints, or do you just need the values as text, with a comma separating them?  Because maybe you should be using a culture-based solution instead of the `string.Split` most people are suggesting...

Comment: Yes I need them in two ints without the comma.

Comment: Is there a maximum precision for the doubles? or any number of decimal places

Comment: This is not, in general, possible. There could easily be more decimals before the decimal point than could fit in an int (over 300, though only 15 significant digits), and the same is true for the part after the decimal point.

Comment: I would only need the precision for two decimal places. Thanks

Answer (score 33, accepted):

This is how you could do it:

```
string s = inputValue.ToString("0.00", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
string[] parts = s.Split('.'); 
int i1 = int.Parse(parts[0]);
int i2 = int.Parse(parts[1]);
```

Comment: Do this converting the value to string is not the best way (it's quite slow), the best option is to do it with maths, converting the `integer` part and then subtracting that value to the original `decimal` value to get the rest.

Answer (score 23):

Manipulating strings can be slow. Try using the following:

```
double number;

long intPart = (long) number;
double fractionalPart = number - intPart;
```

Comment: I think this is the best answer.

Comment: It might help, but it answers a different question. `fractionalPart` is `0.xxxx...`, not `xx`.

Comment: Note that this will cause precision issues under certain conditions. i.e. 55.55 will split as 55 and .549999999997. String Conversion will be more expensive, but will help keep your number integrity.

Answer (score 8):

What programming language you want to use to do this? Most of the language should have a [Modulo operator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulo_operation). C++ example:

```
double num = 10.5;
int remainder = num % 1
```

Answer (score 4):

```
"10.50".Split('.').Select(int.Parse);
```

Answer (score 3):

```
/// <summary>
/// Get the integral and floating point portions of a Double
/// as separate integer values, where the floating point value is 
/// raised to the specified power of ten, given by 'places'.
/// </summary>
public static void Split(Double value, Int32 places, out Int32 left, out Int32 right)
{
    left = (Int32)Math.Truncate(value);
    right = (Int32)((value - left) * Math.Pow(10, places));
}

public static void Split(Double value, out Int32 left, out Int32 right)
{
    Split(value, 1, out left, out right);
}
```

Usage:

```
Int32 left, right;

Split(10.50, out left, out right);
// left == 10
// right == 5

Split(10.50, 2, out left, out right);
// left == 10
// right == 50

Split(10.50, 5, out left, out right);
// left == 10
// right == 50000
```

Answer (score 3):

how about?

```
var n = 1004.522
var a = Math.Floor(n);
var b = n - a;
```

Answer (score 2):

Another variation that doesn't involve string manipulation:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    decimal number = 10123.51m;
    int whole = (int)number;
    decimal precision = (number - whole) * 100;

    Console.WriteLine(number);
    Console.WriteLine(whole);
    Console.WriteLine("{0} and {1}",whole,(int) precision);
    Console.Read();
}
```

Make sure they're decimals or you get the usual strange float/double behaviour.

Answer (score 1):

you can split with string   and then convert into int ...

```
string s = input.ToString(); 
string[] parts = s.Split('.');
```

Answer (score 1):

This function will take time in decimal and converts back into base 60 .

```
    public string Time_In_Absolute(double time)
    {
        time = Math.Round(time, 2);
        string[] timeparts = time.ToString().Split('.');                        
        timeparts[1] = "." + timeparts[1];
        double Minutes = double.Parse(timeparts[1]);            
        Minutes = Math.Round(Minutes, 2);
        Minutes = Minutes * (double)60;
        return string.Format("{0:00}:{1:00}",timeparts[0],Minutes);
        //return Hours.ToString() + ":" + Math.Round(Minutes,0).ToString(); 
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Using Linq. Just clarification of @Denis answer.

```
var parts = "10.50".Split('.').Select(int.Parse);
int i1 = parts.ElementAt(0);
int i2 = parts.ElementAt(1);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
string s = "10.5";
string[] s1 = s.Split(new char[] { "." });
string first = s1[0];
string second = s1[1];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it without going through strings. Example:

```
foreach (double x in new double[]{10.45, 10.50, 10.999, -10.323, -10.326, 10}){
    int i = (int)Math.Truncate(x);
    int f = (int)Math.Round(100*Math.Abs(x-i));
    if (f==100){ f=0; i+=(x<0)?-1:1; }
    Console.WriteLine("("+i+", "+f+")");
}
```

Output:

```
(10, 45)
(10, 50)
(11, 0)
(-10, 32)
(-10, 33)
(10, 0)
```

Won't work for a number like `-0.123`, though. Then again, I'm not sure how it would fit your representation.

Answer (score 0):

I actually just had to answer this in the real world and while @David Samuel's answer did part of it here is the resulting code I used. As said before Strings are way too much overhead. I had to do this calculation across pixel values in a video and was still able to maintain 30fps on a moderate computer.

```
double number = 4140 / 640; //result is 6.46875 for example

int intPart = (int)number; //just convert to int, loose the dec.
int fractionalPart = (int)((position - intPart) * 1000); //rounding was not needed.
//this procedure will create two variables used to extract [iii*].[iii]* from iii*.iii*
```

This was used to solve x,y from pixel count in 640 X 480 video feed.

Answer (score 0):

```
Console.Write("Enter the amount of money: ");
double value = double.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

int wholeDigits = (int) value;
double fractionalDigits = (value - wholeDigits) * 100;
fractionalDigits = (int) fractionalDigits;

Console.WriteLine(
    "The number of the shekels is {0}, and the number of the agurot is {1}",
    wholeDigits, fractionalDigits);
```